# How to get a table on a new web page when a button is Clicked

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datatable

This is my one tag:

```
 <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="ShowOrder" onclick="newTab" />
```

This is my 'aspx.cs' which will be called when button is clicked

```
   protected void newTab(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?id="+txtSearchCustomerByID.Value);
   }
```

What I want is to print my sql table on loaded web tab (new page) when it gets loaded.

My stored procedure is displaying the data of my table where id is equal to "id entered by user in textbox".

Now,

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     int id_no = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
     if (Page.IsPostBack)
         {
         showOrders(id_no);
         } 
     }
```

Now what should I have in 'Default2.aspx' so that I will get my table by using,

```
public void showOrders(int id)
   {
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
   {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("showOrdersSP", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        con.Open();
        .......
   }
   }
```

**I need to use DataTable**

So simply when I clicked, I will get data table on new page

Comment: Try to use QueryString or Session to get the details in another page.

Comment: I edited my code. I've used QueryString for taking the value "id". I want a datatable which contains my table's records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer below code:

```
public void showOrders(int id)
   {
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
   {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlParameter[] p1 = new SqlParameter[1];
        p1[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", id);    
        dt= getRecords_table("showOrdersSP", p1); // you will get your DataTable here

   }
   }

// Common Method for FillYour Tables
 private DataTable getRecords_table(string spname, SqlParameter[] para)
        {
            string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connName"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(spname, con);
            ad.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(para);
            con.Open();
            ad.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            return dt;

        }
```

Hope it will helps you

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I tried it. I then bind "dt" to a gridview, it works but not getting records. It shows an empty table.

Comment: Are you getting records on SQL server by run this  command : `exec showOrdersSP 1`. I mean execute your sp at SQL server ?

Comment: you are saying `dt= getRecords_table("showOrdersSP", p1);` here the `dt` is empty ?

Comment: No. I am doing    dt = getRecords_table("showOrdersSP", p1);
                        orderGrid.DataSource = dt;
                       orderGrid.DataBind();         to print table. Is it correct ?

Comment: put a break point here `dt= getRecords_table("showOrdersSP", p1);` and check the `dt` is filled or not !

Comment: Please upvote and mark my solution if it helps you, thanks

Comment: Directing to "id". As I said I need to use an "id"  from previous page and then   'Request.QueryString["id"]'  and then only I will call my method so it will also be applied to my SP

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was my silly mistake in gridview, I retested and It worked !! Thanks Again !!